# VB.NET Modify Matching with Access Database

Tags: regex, vb.net, dictionary, match, newline

i'm working in a dictionary program

as example if i want to get this line from database:

[image]

i suppose to write this in english textbox:

[image]

but if i wrote it like this:

[image]

no match is found while it is the same no comma

or any other modification except the new line

i failed to modify the code to make the program match a sentence

of words regardless of new line in between

the code of the translation function:

```
Function getexactsubtitles(ByVal content As String) As String
    Try
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim connectionall As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Using adp As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Using tbl As New DataTable
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Subtitles]", connectionall)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@english", String.Concat("%", content, "%"))
                    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                    If adp.Fill(tbl) > 0 Then
                        For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
                            Dim en As String = row.Item("English").Replace("?", "\?")
                            Dim ar As String = row.Item("Arabic")
                            count += Regex.Matches(content, en, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count
                            content = Regex.Replace(content, en, ar, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                        Next
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        MsgBox(IIf(count = 0, "لم يتم العثور على أى تطابق تام داخل قاعدة البيانات", "عدد الحالات المطابقة تماماً التى عثر عليها داخل قاعدة البيانات (" & " " & count & " " & ") من الجمل والكلمات"))
        Return content
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    getexactsubtitles = ""
End Function
```

please notice this part:

```
Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Subtitles]", connectionall)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@english", String.Concat("%", content, "%"))
```

this is my try to do the job but for some reason it is not working

code for translation button:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
TextBox2.Text = getexactsubtitles(TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the linefeed? Using wildcards will adversely  affect performance and will not solve your problem.

Comment: this was just a simple example, the dictionary is supposed to work on a text consisting of thousands of line, any manual modification can't be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using `Regex.Replace()` and the pattern is stored in the first column of a table. 
And all you need is for `" "` to also match newlines.

I think you should consider replacing `" "` with `\s+` in your pattern, since it matches any of these characters: `[\r\n\t\f ]`. [More examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

The "+" in `\s+` is to repeat one or more times. That way, it can match

> How are you [space] + [cr] + [lf]
>
> today tommy?

#### Solution

In the example you provided,

```
[English]                             |  [Arabic]
how\s+are\s+you\s+today\s+tommy\?     |  asking about tommy's health
```

- **Aternative**: if you can't store that pattern in the database, replace it in your code (this is not quite efficient)

  ```
  Dim en As String = row.Item("English").Replace("?", "\?").Replace(" ","\s+")
  ```

Also, I noticed you are escaping the question marks. You should also be aware there might be some other [metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). So please consider using `Regex.Escape()` instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that `\s+` also matches consecutive spaces as in
`"how[space][space][space][space]are you[space][space][space][space]tommy?"`

Comment: first you are brilliant, second i have replace your (\s+) in the code and worked great so i don't understand why you said it's not quite efficient, third could you please tell me more about (regex.escape()). and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: **2** Since this is a dictionary, it's not quite efficient assuming it will be replacing many strings, triggered several times, obtaining the same result every time. Instead of replacing it every time, you could simply store the result pattern (with `\s+`) directly in the database. That way, `.Replace(" ","\s+")` would only be executed once per string. **3** [Regex.Escape()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) (check the link) is suggested instead of `.Replace("?", "\?")` and it guarantees a sanitized text for your pattern.